# Play and Hibernate Changing Model Class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I'm using the play framework in combination with hibernate, like this official example: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/computer-database-jpa.
When I update a model, e.g. add a property, I get an error message, that the column does not exist. I thought play is automatically migrating the database schema, when the model is modified.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. I had to add

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

to the persitence.xml